# How to avoid twice adding UIView on not ended block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, block, dispatch-async

I have a "loading" view added to an uiimageview to indicate the image is being loaded, then on a dispatch async I am charging the image and removing the "loading" view once it has finished, problem is that if I call twice this method the "loading" view is added twice and the second one is never removed.

Edited:

on view.h

```
UIView *loading;
```

on view.m

```
loading = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
loading.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
loading.alpha = 0.8;
loading.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
loading.center = CGPointMake(imageView.frame.size.width/2, imageView.frame.size.height/2);

if (![imageView.subviews containsObject:loading]) {
    [imageView addSubview:loading];
}
dispatch_queue_t downloadFoto = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadFoto, ^{
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[selectedImage objectForKey:@"url"]]]];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (image) {
            [imageView setImage:image];
            [imageView setNeedsLayout];
            if ([imageView.subviews containsObject:loading]) {
                [loading removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If this is called just once or if I call it after the loading is already removed everything works fine, the problem is if I call this before the block had finished.

**Thank you guys, this is my solution at the end.**

```
if (!blackView) {
UIActivityIndicatorView *load = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
blackView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blackView.alpha = 0.8;
blackView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
blackView.center = CGPointMake(fotoVisual.frame.size.width/2, fotoVisual.frame.size.height/2);
load.center = CGPointMake(blackView.frame.size.width/2, blackView.frame.size.height/2);
[load startAnimating];
[blackView addSubview:load];


[fotoVisual setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previewImagen.png"]];
descripcionFotoView.text = [selectedImage objectForKey:@"titulo"];

}
if (![fotoVisual.subviews containsObject:blackView]) {
    [fotoVisual addSubview:blackView];
}
dispatch_queue_t downloadFoto = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadFoto, ^{
    [fotoVisual setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[selectedImage objectForKey:@"url"]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previewImagen.png"]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [blackView removeFromSuperview];
            blackView = nil;
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadFoto);
```

Comment: Is `loading` an ivar or local variable? Can you show the creation of it...

Comment: is an ivar...I'll edit my question

Comment: you can try this to remove every view from imageview , [imageView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: containsObject will always be a false because each time you create a new loading view. Try to add a tag to the loading view, anche check if image view has a view with tag. If there is one you can be sure that you have already added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue you have is that you are creating a new `loading` view each time, which is not what you want. Your `[imageView.subviews containsObject:loading]` will never be true as you make a new `loading` view each time.

You could change the creation logic to do the checking like this

```
if (!loading) {
  // configure loading
  [imageView addSubview:loading];
}
```

Then modify your call back to something like

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  if (image) {
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageView setNeedsLayout];
    [loading removeFromSuperview];
    loading = nil;
  }
});
```

Is there any specific reason you are using `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`?

Comment: no, is just that in another post I saw that it might be used the sync one...  let me try...

Comment: The `sync` vs `async` has not bearing here but... I tend to just use `async` where possible to avoid deadlocks. I'll know when I need `sync` which is normally not that often

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem, but in conjunction with the panayot answer i got the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Add you `loading` subview in `dispatch_async` block

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadFoto = dispatch_queue_create("Get Photo", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadFoto, ^{

if (!loading.superview) {
// we assume your loading view doesn't have a superview so we can add it to imageView
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        
     [imageView addSubview:loading];
  };
}

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[selectedImage objectForKey:@"url"]]]];


        if (image) {
          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [imageView setImage:image];
            [imageView setNeedsLayout];
            if ([imageView.subviews containsObject:loading]) {
                [loading removeFromSuperview];
            }
          });
        }
});
```

For Async image downloading you can also use [SDWebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
Just download the project and add SDWebimage folder to your project and use as folows

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[selectedImage objectForKey:@"url"]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

This will also cache the image.

Comment: what difference this will make ?

Comment: An edit has been added to my answer. Please take a look

Comment: Tried and still getting the same issue, I tried that sdk, and works great, but still needs the loading view..

Comment: Have you tried to check if your loading has a superview like `if(loading.superview)`? See my edited code above

Comment: yes tried with the same result, in conjunction with the paul.s answer i got the full answer, +1 for the sdk is awesome ;)